# CTRL-a and CTRL-e map incorrectly in tmux

Tags: command-line, keyboard, tmux, shortcut-keys

I like to use command-line commands `CTRL-a` (beginning of line) and `CTRL-e` (end of line), but when I start a tmux session, these commands don't work. CTRL-key seems to be interpreted as caret `^`, as in the terminal I see `^A` and `^E` respectively. `CTRL-b` works without any issues.

I'm using xfce4-terminal and zshell, if that makes any difference.

Setting `set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'` in .tmux.conf did not help.

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: I don't remember the details (hence only a comment) but it sounds like you need to enable emacs-style keyboard shortcuts in either tmux or zsh or both.

Comment: try `TERM=vt100 && export TERM`

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the reply, I searched for emacs-style bindings specifically, and found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520371 which solved my problem. I never knew the issue was originating from zsh, considering in zsh these bindings work.

Comment: Great! Could you post an answer explaining what you did?

Comment: @terdon Done! It's a very short answer, but it explains what solved my issue. Thanks again for your reply, it helped me to search more accurately for information.

Comment: Great! And thanks for taking the time to post an answer!

Answer (score 6):

After making the following changes to my dot files, I was able to use emacs style key bindings also inside a tmux session.

```
# .zshrc
bindkey -e

# .tmux.conf
set -g mode-keys emacs
set -g status-keys emacs
```

[This answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240683/how-to-force-emacs-style-status-keys-in-tmux/39520371#39520371) helped me solve my issue.